# JavaScript issue. if('#id'.value = '#a different id'.value)

Tags: javascript, html

```
if('#inputSuccess4'.value = '#inputSuccess5'.value){
    $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
    $('#emailcheck3').addClass('has-success');
    $('#emailcheck4').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
}
```

I am doing a JS validation for the email input and confirm email address input. If the two value are the same, that bit of code makes a green tick. The problem must be in the first line of code. Btw #inputSuccess4 and #inputSuccess5 are just the id's for the two input boxes.

```
if(('#inputSuccess4').value = ('#inputSuccess').value)
```

this didn't work either

EDIT :

the full function including the html code just in case the syntax error(s) are elsewhere.

```
    <div id="emailcheck" class="form-group has-feedback ">
        <input placeholder="Email address" onblur="validateEmail()" onkeyup="validateEmail()" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess4" aria-describedby="inputSuccess4Status" required/>
        <span id="emailcheck2" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback " aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="emailcheck3" class="form-group has-feedback ">
        <input placeholder="Confirm email address" onblur="validateEmail2()" onkeyup="validateEmail2()" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess5" aria-describedby="inputSuccess5Status" required/>
        <span id="emailcheck4" class="glyphicon form-control-feedback " aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
```

and the js

```
function validateEmail2() {
        var email = document.getElementById("inputSuccess5").value; 

            if(email != ""){    

                if(('#inputSuccess4').value = ('#inputSuccess5').value){

                    $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-error');
                    $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
                    $('#emailcheck3').addClass('has-success');
                    $('#emailcheck4').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
                    }

                else {
                    $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-success');
                    $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
                    $('#emailcheck3').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#emailcheck4').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
                    }
            }
            else {
            $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-success');
            $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-ok');
            $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-error');
            $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
            }
        }
```

Comment: you do _assign_ `=` instead _compare_ `==`. Anyway you try get property `value` from string instead of jQuery object. and also for getting value in jQuery - use `.val()`

Comment: `$('#inputSuccess4').val() == $('#inputSuccess5').val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String does not have property `value`. Use `$('#inputSuccess4').val()`.

Also comparison operator is `==` / `<=` / `>=` / `!=`. While `if (v = x)` means assignment in condition (same as `x == true`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all if with a `=` usage is not a comparation, you should use `==` and function should be like below

```
if($('#inputSuccess4').val() == $('#inputSuccess5').val()){
    $('#emailcheck3').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#emailcheck4').removeClass('glyphicon-remove');
    $('#emailcheck3').addClass('has-success');
    $('#emailcheck4').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
}
```

Comment: Solution is perfect. I very much appreciate it